# re.sub not affecting values inside between brackets

Tags: python, regex

```
a = re.sub('"', '-','<font color="#000000"face="Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" size="-2">10’0”</font>')
```

This result is :

```
<font color=-#000000- face=-Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif- size=--2->10’0”</font>
```

Why won't re.sub affect the 10'0" inside the brackets?

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? I couldn't find this through a search.

Comment: Why should it affect the ```'``` when you have mentioned double quotes ```"``` in the ```sub``` function? Have a look at some of the questions below if you want to add options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the type of quote you are searching for. Also, you can use the `|` character to search for both `'` and `’`:

```
import re
a = re.sub('"|’|”', "-",'<font color="#000000"face="Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" size="-2">10’0”</font>')
```

Output:

```
'<font color=-#000000-face=-Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif- size=--2->10-0-</font>'
```